# Conditional Formatting of Dates in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am trying to make conditional formatting for Dates in Excel. 
The cells should change the color depeding on when the Date is due. 
If it is due in less than 30 days it should be red. 
If it is due in less than 60 days it should be yellow.
If it is due in less than 90 days it should be green.

If have following Formula `=DATEDIF(TODAY();E:E;"d")<30`as a conditional formatting rule for the start. 
The strange part is that it works if I have it in a cell. It returns the value true for the values in "E" that are due in less than 30 days. However I cannot apply this rule in conditional formatting. It does not give me an error. It simply does nothing...

Can this be solved with conditional formatting or should I write a VBA script?

Comment: Just use a regular `If` statement to determine it, I don't see why you'd need `DatedIf`.

Comment: Instead of referring to `E:E`, select just one cell in the same row to apply it to and make it refer to the same specific row in that column, `E1` for example. As long as you get rid of any `$`s that Excel automatically applies, then it will still be a relative reference and you can extend the range it applies to in the "Manage Rules" menu after you have gotten it working for one cell.

Comment: I will assume you have titles in the first row.  So in E2 put the following conditional formula: `=TODAY() - E2<30` then use the formatting desired.  In the applies to fiels put the `E:E`

Comment: It is working but only for Field E2. Not for the other fields.

Comment: It is not working. It is just always Coloring E2 and E1 I only want the cells to be colored where the dates are in range of 30 days

Comment: Which column contains the values you want colored in?

Comment: The Column E contains all Date values. For each Date value entered a check with today should be performed and colored if one of the described rules matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Excel does some wacky stuff that it thinks is helpful when you're trying to apply conditional formatting to a range (it's usually more of a hindrance than help).

Follow these steps:

1. Select the first cell with a date value in it, I'm assuming `E2`.
2. Click on Conditional Formatting -> New Rule.
3. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
4. Paste in the formula `=DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"d")<30` and select whatever formatting options you want. Click `OK`.
5. Go back into conditional formatting by clicking on "Manage Rules".
6. In the Applies to field, change it to `=E2:E200`, or whatever the last row of the range is. Alternatively you can use a `named range` if you want to set up something a little more dynamic.

That rule now applies to the whole range.

Comment: Thx that was exactly what i was searching for. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I used the following formulas:

```
=DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"d")<30
=DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"d")<60
=DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"d")<90
```