# Conditional formatting in excel when a date is coming due

Tags: excel

I have a list of due dates in a row. I want to highlight each date as orange when it is -30days from when it is due. Can anyone instruct me on how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you struggling with the correct formula or do you need a step by step instruction on how to apply conditional formatting?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517834/conditional-formatting-of-dates-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

To do this,

1. Have a [=Today()] cell to be your constant date
2. Go to the conditional formatting tab and select highlight cells rule
3. Go to "more rules" at the bottom
4. Ensure the rule type is "Format cells that contain"
5. Edit the rule decription so it looks like the picture below.
6. Basically, that rule is saying highlight the cells that are between today's date and 30 days from then

[What your conditional format statement should look like where K16 is my today function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR6uO.png)